# Making measurements on the object

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, measure

I use the objects that I scan with the photogrammetry method exactly in unity. So when I create a cube and expand this cube to the extent that I want to measure, I give an example. The z value gives the value in meters. What I want to do is to measure the distance with an object to be created between the two points I click on the object and the value I will get over it. How can I make this happen?
I've tried the code below but nothing draws.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class olcumYap : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer lineRend;
    private Vector2 mousePos;
    private Vector2 startMousePos;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text distanceText;

    private float distance;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lineRend = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRend.positionCount = 2;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            startMousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            lineRend.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(startMousePos.x, startMousePos.y, 0f));
            lineRend.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 0f));
            distance = (mousePos - startMousePos).magnitude;
            distanceText.text = distance.ToString("F2") + "metre";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try debugging the line positions to see if the problem is the line renderer or the positions.

```
Debug.Log(<position>);
print(<position>);
```

It is generally a good practice to log something if it doesnt work to find the issuee.